# Why DOCTYPE is required in HTML(ANGULAR)?

Tags: html, angular, doctype, angular-aot, angularbuild

If in Angular with AOT , all typescript, HTML and CSS code gets converted into JS after complication, then why we need to mention DOCTYPE in HTML?

Comment: Because that's how browsers figure out what flavor of html you're using...? JavaScript compilation doesn't matter here, what's your actual question?

Comment: The only doctype tag (and html, and head and body tag) you use is in index.html

Answer (score -1):

Angular's Ahead-of-Time (AOT) compilation process converts TypeScript, HTML, and CSS code into JavaScript during build time, the DOCTYPE declaration in HTML remains essential for defining the document type, ensuring standards compliance, improving browser compatibility, and facilitating error handling and validation.